# JavaScript eval how to use in groovy or grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I want to assign a value to an existing variable, but the name of the variable is dynamic. How do I do that

```
def a1 = 0;
def b = 1;
eval("a${b} =1;");
print a1
```

Comment: What has this to do with javascript?

Comment: Think about using Map instead of variables. So it will be possible to use dynanic names in it.

Comment: Assuming you want to use Groovy Eval just like you use javascript eval, it will be difficult assign the values to primitive variables dynamically. You can use map with the Groovy eval function like following: 
        Map m = ['a': 1]
        def val = 9898
        def field = 'a'
        Eval.xyz(m, field, val, 'x[y] = z')
         assert m.a == val

Answer (score 0):

No need for javascript here:

```
def name = 'someName';
def value = 'someValue';

new GroovyShell(this.binding).evaluate("${name} = '${value}'")

assert someName == value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this doesn't answer your question exactly, an easy way around this is to drop your dynamic variables as map keys instead...  avoid needing to eval them

```
def b = 1
def map = [:]
map."a${b}" = 1
assert map."a${b}" == 1
println(map)   // result is   [a1:1]
```